# Unnecessary work done for kitchen faucet leak?

Tags: plumbing, leak, faucet

We've had this kitchen faucet installed several years ago. A few months ago I noticed a leak under the sink. It appeared to be coming from one of the dark hoses (with the white connector) only when the water was running. I tightened one of the hoses by hand and that seemed to resolve the problem. A few days ago I noticed it was leaking again and called a plumber. He said it was due to condensation and that the pipes should have insulation on them. He also said a pex tee was installed wrong and needed to be replaced. After several years why would condensation be so bad just this year? It was also not leaking near the tee. Wondering if we were overcharged for unnecessary work.
[image]
[image: insulation on pipes]

Comment: "I tightened one of the hoses by hand and that seemed to resolve the problem. A few days ago I noticed it was leaking again and called a plumber." - Well, if tightening it again didn't work.... you did try tightening it again, right? Well then they prob tightened everything and then did what they could to solve the problem. Which was actually *you* calling a plumber to turn a nut. What did you expect them to do, charge you $150 to tighten things for 5m?

Comment: They did everything they could possibly think of because if this was an ongoing problem, and "I've tightened things before" then that wasn't going to cut it. That's an abnormal amount of exposed pipe so their solution wasn't unwarranted. If the drain leaks again, prob needs a new o-ring somewhere.

Comment: You forgot to say what work was performed by the person(s) charging you. And if you agreed/paid it, it is not overcharging. That said, that undersink plumbing you have is just plain hideous, for many reasons.

Comment: The black hoses with white connector carry water from your faucet valve down and back up to your sprayer/faucet nozzle. The white connector gets yanked up and down every time you pull out the sprayer, but it should be designed to hold up well over time. Can you clarify exactly what you did when you "...tightened one of the hoses by hand and that seemed to resolve the problem." Which hose, where, and what exactly did you tighten?

Comment: The white connector appears to be connecting your pullout sprayer to the faucet body.  What model of faucet is it?  (The condensation line you were fed is BS.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too late now, you paid.

There will be no condensation unless your water temperature is below 40F and the humidity in house is above 70%.

As for the adaptor been installed wrong who knows, shows us the picture.

FYI, those pipes are newer thermally insulated as long they are inside the home, and you do not live in Arctic circle.

Comment: Didn't pay yet. (: Don't have a pic of the old tee. It was crimped sloppily but there was no leak at the tee.

Answer (score 6):

That white connector attaches the water supply from your faucet to the pull-out hose in your kitchen faucet. I've found those connectors to be pretty reliable - although anything can fail under certain conditions. If water is leaking from there it is highly unlikely to be the result of condensation unless you live in the tropics and even then I doubt it would be enough to classify as a leak.
Anyway, you seem to have solved the problem but we can't tell you from the picture if the work on the pex was needed or not. Sorry - caveat emptor.